# NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0 not behaving as expected

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have this simple method to put the first element of an array at the end and move everything down by one index:

```
-(NSArray*)backUpNotes:(NSArray*)notes {
    NSMutableArray* newNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:notes];
    Note* note = [newNotes objectAtIndex:0];
    [newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [newNotes addObject:note];

    return (NSArray*)newNotes;
}
```

the array notes contains two Note* objects, Note A and Note B.
after the line

```
Note* note = [newNotes objectAtIndex:0];
```

note contains Note A -- as expected.
After the line

```
[newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

newNotes ONLY contains Note A --- This is NOT expected. Note A is at index 0, and I can see that from the debugger. If I instead do

```
[newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:1];
```

newNotes still ONLY contains Note A -- That is expected, since I'm removing note B in that case. It seems to me that I cannot for the life of me remove Note A from this array. I even tried doing:

```
[newNotes removeObject:note];
```

and still having newNotes containing ONLY note A -- definitely unexpected.

Any insight would be amazing.

Comment: Is there a reason for the addObject line where you add the note back?

Comment: There is no questions that `removeObjectAtIndex:` works exactly as explained in the documentation. I'm afraid that it's probably you confusing note B for note A.

Comment: yes, it's to put the first object at the end of the array. The method is to shift everything down one.

Comment: Tom - I promise you, I am not. Is there anything else (possibly the way my Note class is created) or some other odd memory related issue that could be causing this?

Comment: Try this: `NSLog(@"Before: %p/%p", [newNotes objectAtIndex:0], [newNotes objectAtIndex:1]); [newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:0]; NSLog(@"After: %p", [newNotes objectAtIndex:0]);` If the object wasn't removed, before and after will be the same.

Comment: I'm seeing something very odd here. I AM getting Note B remaining, but it has taken on ALL of the member properties of Note A...

Comment: Note B copies Note A before it enter the backup method?

Comment: Terry, no, I can watch in the debugger that Note B doesn't take on Note A's properties until after I removeObjectAtIndex:0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray* newNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:notes];
for (Note *n in newNotes) {
    if ([n isEqual:note]) {
        [newNotes removeObject:n];
        break;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
int x = 0;
NSMutableArray* newNotes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:notes];
for (Note *n in newNotes) {
    if ([n isEqual:note]) {
        break;
    }
    ++x;
}
[newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:x];
```

Comment: Same unexpected result for both of them. This is just completely baffling me.

Comment: Try `[newNotes removeObjectAtIndex:[newNotes indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:note]];`